# Pusher: iOS Push Notification not arriving on phone

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pusher

I am trying to send push notifications for my app using Pusher.

I am following their tutorial (https://pusher.com/tutorials/push-notifications-ios/) to set it up. Thus far, I have enabled Push Notifications in XCode, created an instance and copied their code snippet.

Here is my AppDelegate.swift file (only relevant parts are included):

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let pushNotifications = PushNotifications.shared

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.pushNotifications.start(instanceId: [instanceId)
        self.pushNotifications.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        try? self.pushNotifications.addDeviceInterest(interest: "hello")
        return true
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        self.pushNotifications.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        self.pushNotifications.handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

I am sending the push notification with the command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $SECRET_KEY" \
     -X POST "https://INSTANCE_ID.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/INSTANCE_ID/publishes" \
     -d '{"interests":["hello"],"apns":{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"Hello","body":"Hello, world!"}}}}'
```

After executing the curl command, I get the following message:

```
{"publishId":[publishId]}
```

However, no notification shows up on the iPhone that I am testing it on. The app is running in the background. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the notification shows up on the iPhone when the app in the foreground?

Comment: No it is not. It says it is published (hence publishId) in the terminal, but never appears on my iPhone.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth to get quicker solution, share a Github link of an sample app with same code setup.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-check all the points mentioned in the link first: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

ensure your apns certificate is valid and you have set the appropriate capabilities in XCODE for push notifications

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the release certificate, then only the release app can receive the push.

1. Configure certificates and codes，plist...
2. XCode->Product->Achive->Release..., upload .ipa.
3. Install the app in testfight, then Push and receive notifications。